# Python binds for adorocinema

Tags: python, module

someone knows if exists a module, in python, to query the site "AdoroCinema" (it's a IMDB clone in Brazilian Portuguese) like the IMDB module?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I wrote a simple class to do this.
If someone wants to try: https://github.com/allangood/adorocinema